# data structure for query substring and contains substring in a collection of strings

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Recently, I met two use cases

1. efficiently query whether a given string `word` is a substring of some elements of a collection of strings.
2. efficiently query whether some elements of a collection of strings are substring of a given string `word`.

```
class StringSet {
    
    void add(String s);

    void contains(String s);

    void remove(String s);

    List<String> getAllSubstringsOfGivenWord(String s);
    
    List<String> getAllStringsContainsGivenWord(String s);

}
```

For example, the collection of String is `{"abc", "dab", "bcd"}`, then `getAllStringsContainsGivenWord("ab") --> ["abc", "dab"]`,  `getAllSubstringsOfGivenWord("dabc") --> ["abc", "dab"]`

Which kind of data structure suits for these kinds of use cases?

Answer (score 1):

What level of efficiency are you looking for? How complex can the `add` and `remove` operations be?

Are there any constraints or limits to the problem space? eg: the number or length of the words, the max length of the substring to look for, letter-casing sensitivity, alphabets to consider.

I'd suggest taking a look into [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), [Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree), and [Generalized Suffix Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_suffix_tree).

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions. I will take a look and clarify more clearly.